# How to get the starting weekday of a month in a future year using date() in php

Tags: php, date, mktime

I am using a date() format to return the starting weekday of a month. The code I have below is how I am attempting to achieve this. For the current year (2018) this works as normal. For example This month is august and the starting weekday is a Wednesday so it will return a 3 for Wednesday. (It works so far)

As we advance the year to 2019 it starts to get the starting weekday wrong.
For example January 2019 starts on a Tuesday so it should return 2 but returns 1. (one day out)

This error seems to be cumulative so if we go to 2020 then it is 2 days out etc.
I have tried so hard to format this Date() correctly but to no avail. Is this even the correct way to do this?

Code:

```
$future_month = 5 /*for January 2019*/     
$starting_weekday = date('N',mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', strtotime('+'.$future_month.' months', strtotime(date('Y-m-01')))), 1));
```

Many Thanks

Cameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes this much more complicated than it needs to be.

```
$dt = new DateTime('first day of +5 months')
$dt->format('N'); // "2"
```

Comment: I cant get this to return a 2, instead it seems to create an array with 3 variables:
Date, timezone_type and Timezone

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this? I am formatting it with format('N') no?

Comment: $dt is the object, format() returns "2", you have to assign that value to a variable...

Comment: so I should put $starting_weekday = $dt after it?
Sorry I think im still a bit confused haha @Devon

Comment: no...  `$starting_weekday = $dt->format('N');`  this is pretty basic, I think you need to take some more time to learn the language and programming prior to building something out...